# NODE.JS function callback to render page

Tags: node.js

I have a function getthem() that checks a mongo db for listings and returns name,streamurl for it.

I pass those as var stream to the renderme that renders the /dashboard page.

My problem is that i get the console.log("END OF FIND:"+JSON.stringify(stream))

to show my test input, but nothing goes to the render.

im using ejs to render. How can i get the result passed to the page ?

```
router.get('/dashboard', function (req, res) {

    var foo = getthem();


        function getthem() {


        var group = "tesint";
        console.log('geting for group : ' + group);
        var mdlListings = require('../models/listings.js');
        var myresult = "tet";

        mdlListings.find({}, "name streamurl", function (err, data) {
            if (err) {
                console.error(err);
                return;
            }
            if (data === null) {
                console.log("No results");
                return;
            }

            var stream = { };
            data.forEach(function (streams) {

                console.log("Got " + streams.name + "  " + streams.streamurl);
                stream[streams.name] = streams.streamurl;
              //  stream += 'name: '+streams.name+'},{streamurl: '+streams.streamurl;
               // console.log("stram arry "+stream[streams.name] )
               console.log("END OF FIND:"+JSON.stringify(stream))
            }, renderme(stream));
            //    console.log("Result:", votes);


            //var myresult = Object.keys(stream).map(function (name) {
            //    return { name: name, url: stream[name] };
            //})

            console.log("before return stream "+stream);
            return stream;
        });


    }

        function renderme(resa) {
            console.log("RESA"+JSON.stringify(resa))
           var resa = JSON.stringify(resa);
            res.render('dashboard', {
                    title: 'Dashboard',
                    user: req.user,
                    listing: resa
                }
            )
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're passing the result of `renderme(stream)` as a second argument to `forEach()`. `renderme(stream)` is then evaluated immediately before your `forEach()` callback is called, when `stream` is still an empty object. My guess is you want something like this:

```
data.forEach(function (streams) {
  console.log("Got " + streams.name + "  " + streams.streamurl);
  stream[streams.name] = streams.streamurl;
  console.log("END OF FIND:"+JSON.stringify(stream))
});
renderme(stream);
```

Answer (score -1):

Actually i figure that why would i pass the function as i could just do whatever i need to directly in there.

That worked perfectly, thanks for the tip.

```
data.forEach(function (streams) {

            console.log("Got " + streams.name + "  " + streams.streamurl);
            stream[streams.name] = streams.streamurl;

        });

        res.render('dashboard', {
                title: 'Dashboard',
                user: req.user,
                listing: data
            }
        )
```